# How to trigger a ListBoxItem's style change on the underlying object state change?

Tags: wpf, triggers, listbox, styles, listboxitem

I have a basic setup of a `ListBox` with its `ItemSource` property set to `ObservableCollection<Human>`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Humans}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <!-- Some setters -->
    </Style>
</ListBox>
```

`Human` is defined like this:

```
public class Human 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }

  public override string ToString() => this.Name;
}
```

So we have a `Human` object living as a source of each of the list box's items and the default behavior of its string representation (`Name` property in this case) displayed.

Now, I'd like the displayed `Human.Name` value to be formatted bold when `IsAnswered` changes to `true`. How to achieve this?

Comment: By a DataTrigger in the ItemContainerStyle or a Binding in the ItemTemplate. Human must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the PropertyChanged event in the IsAnswered setter.

Comment: But how to point `DataTrigger` in `ItemContainerStyle` at `IsAnswered`?

Comment: The DataContext of the item container is always the data model, in your case the Human instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the item container is always the data model, in your case the `Human` instance. Therefore simply bind to the `DataContext`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnswered}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>           
</ListBox>
```

As already noted in the comments, you must let `Human` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The property `IsAnswered` must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Otherwise the changes of the property will not be propagated.

Comment: @Luuklag ponder if I indeed "showed the effort" like you suggest my question would be more concise and easy to understand **or more bloated with unneeded context?** I see your point, but this site's founding rationale is first and foremost answering questions and not policing others to "do enough effort" to be admitted into some elite club. If one thinks I did not enough effort, one can happily ignore my question and let the others who maybe think otherwise answer. Luckily, my question made it to got a valid and helpful answer, thus really invalidating any of the closing concerns.

Comment: I agree with your points. But consider once again my point. Less is more. Adding additional context can be helpful like you say, but can as easily (I would argue that even easier) be unhelpful and make the question **less focused**. And that was the purported reason for closing. The passage in text I could render in code is only one easily understood sentence - would it really change anything in this case? Consider also that I was writing it from home, with no access to the production machine. Producing valid code from memory is not easy and an error-prone task.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I edited slightly the answer following your advice and adding more context. Checked on the production code. It works.

Comment: I am really grateful for your input. I think we have a simple case of chicken-and-egg conundrum. I would've formulated my question better for the experts to parse...if only I also would be an expert like them and hence intimately knew what they require. But then maybe I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place :)

Comment: Yeah I see the difficulty in deciding what to leave and what to include. That's why I said: when we provide the minumal code, that does nothing but exactly reproduce the problem, then you can't do wrong. The art is not to decide what to leave but to take your time to reduce the code, strip off all the distracting noise, and still have minimum viable code we can review or even debug. If you manage to do this, nobody ever complains. People also give upvotes for good questions. If I find such a question I feel engaged to answer it. There is no time consuming interogation just to get more info.

Comment: I'm glad you are that kind. Nice conversation, no attacking, thank you